# SqfLite data type for mixed Character (Flutter(Dart))

Tags: database, sqldatatypes, sqflite

What is the data type of **Mixed** Character like '123ABC456' in SqfLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. 'VARCHAR' is the answer here.